# Storing random Number whiten an array

Tags: java, arrays

I am making a roll the dice game for a project I'm doing for school. I have a random Generator which is called via `dice.rollDice()` which then gives the result of the random number.

When I press a key the result of `dice.rollDice` is displayed on the console. I need to store the results in an array so far I have the array created

```
int[] randomNumbers = new int[7];
```

I'm not sure how to store the results of the `dice.rollDice` in the index
I know to store an array the code  is `randomNumbers[] = dice.rollDice()` is there a more efficient way to do this
Any help is appreciated

### Class `Dice`:

```java
class Dice { 

    Random random = new Random(); // assigns random number generator Random();
    
    public int rollDice() {
        int output = 1 + random.nextInt(6); //returns a random number between 1 and 6
        return(output);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the rollDice method and the dice class?

Comment: @Trillyy i just added it above

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I declare and initialize an array in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200621/how-do-i-declare-and-initialize-an-array-in-java)

Comment: offtopic: calling the method `dice.roll()` would be much more elegant ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am answering your homework question because you have shown, that you have tried to solve it yourself. Please try to make sure you understand **why** this solves the problem.

---

You want several results, but your method only returns a single value. You can either embrace the fact that it it a single `Die` and call the function in a loop, or you can have your class represent multiple `Dice`. In the following I will show you how to implement the first approach:

```
class Die { // note, the singular of dice is "Die"
    private Random random = new Random();
    private int sideCount;

    public Die(int sideCount) {
        this.sideCount = sideCount;
    }

    public int roll() {
        int output = 1 + random.nextInt(sideCount); //returns a random number between 1 and sideCount
        return(output);
    }

    public int rollRepeatedly(int count) {
        int[] results = new int[count];
        // here we call the method we already have in a loop
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            results[i] = roll();
        }
        return results;
    }
}
```

And now call your code like:

```
Die die = new Die(6);
randomNumbers[] = die.rollRepeatedly(7);
```

---

If you wanted to implement a class called `Dice`, it should have a constructor parameter `count`have two options.

1. Save the count parameter as a member variable. In your `roll()` method, create an array of results and fill it in a loop.
2. Reuse the `Die` class by creating an array of `Die` in `Dice`, making it the size of `count`. Then roll them individually when calling `dice.roll()`. You could imagine how this array could even store `Die`s with different `sideCount`s, depending on the type of game you implement